# Make API calls in a loop in PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, azure-databricks

I want to make an API call and get a json response for 350,000 rows. The below code is taking forever. How can I parallelize them in PySpark to improve performance?

```
%python
import requests, json
dict_error = {}
dataCollect = df_url.collect()  //df_url is a spark dataframe
for row in dataCollect:
  response = requests.get(row["url"])
  dict_json_response = response.json()
  if (dict_json_response['responseCode']!=1) : dict_error[row['id']] = dict_json_response['responseCode']
print(dict_error)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to repartition the DataFrame and call the function as shown below.

```py
import requests, json

def make_api_call(row):
    response = requests.get(row["url"])
    dict_json_response = response.json()
    if dict_json_response['status'] != 1:
        return row['id'], dict_json_response['status']
    else:
        return None
```

Call the function with repartition.

```py
errors = df.repartition(4096).rdd.map(lambda row: make_api_call(row)).filter(lambda x: x is not None).collect()
```

Then, convert it to a dictionary.

```py
dict_error = dict(errors)
print(dict_error)
```

Output:

[image]

Again, all this depends on your Databricks number of workers.
I executed this with 8 workers with 14 GB memory and 4 cores each. So, in total, there were 32 cores, and it took **21 minutes** for `350000` rows.
If you increase the number of workers and adjust the number of partitions, it will take less time.

**Note**: Make sure all of your cores are utilized; by setting the number of partitions in multiples of your total cores, you can achieve that. In this case, there are 32 cores, so it will be `32 * 4`, `32 * 10`, or `32 * 100`.

Comment: Thank you @JayashankarGS.  I will try the above.  I am running on 1 Driver and 1 - 4 Workers (scaling with minimum 1)  each with 14 GB 4 Cores.

Comment: So you are having total 16 cores. and repartition in multiples of 16. I suggest to give 8192.